# Как вернуть значение функции в родительский модуль

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь написать простой скрипт. Описал в server.js:

```
var UserMethods = require('../User');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var params = UserMethods.userGetParams(req.query.user_id); //Как???

    res.render('index', {
        status: params.status,
        points: params.points
    });

});
```

И никак не пойму как банально получить данные с этой функции?? Возращать в асинхронной функции никак. колбэк ок.. но как его использовать из дочернего модуля в родительском?

Comment: Обратите внимание на способы 1 и 2 по ссылке выше.

Comment: PS *сколько раз вам надо дать ссылку на ответ, чтобы вы его уже наконец-то прочитали?* Вы же уже задавали вопрос про проблемы с асинхронностью!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, и каким боком их применить? куда колбэк возвращать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте тот ответ внимательнее. Колбэк не нужно возвращать...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, то есть правильно понимаю смысл колбэка в том что функция выполнится только после того как получит результат другой функции(где указан колбэк) в свой аргумент?

Comment: да, вы понимаете правильно

Answer (score 0):

Есть много статей на этот вечный вопрос, вот пример из статьи "**Понимание callback-функций (колбеков)**" на хабре:

```
// определяем нашу функцию с аргументом callback
function some_function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // переменная, генерирующая случайное число в интервале между arg1 и arg2
    var my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
    // теперь всё готово и  мы вызываем callback, куда передаём наш результат
    callback(my_number);
}
// вызываем функцию
some_function(5, 15, function (num) {
    // эта анонимная функция выполнится после вызова callback-функции
    console.log("callback called! " + num);
});
```